# How to simplify the mybatis @Result(column = "", property = "")

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

In the following figure, I did not use the configuration file of Mybatis , instead, I used annotations. This forces me to write some duplicate code.How to simplify these codes?[image]

Comment: May be you can create a custom annotation that extends @Results and provide the above definition in the custom annotation. You can then use `@CustomAnnotation`

Comment: Thank you, I try it